# How To display Task Triggers in TaskScheduler?

Tags: c++, qt, scheduled-tasks

I'd like to print a specific trigger of a task that I created , how can I do that in C++ using QT Framework , what is the best way ?
also , what's the best way to create a dynamic scheduler with multiple tasks and have the ability to retrieve each task information?

Comment: QT is written in C++, you specifically ask for a C++ answer. Tags changed.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to manage task through a scheduler you should use the [`QProcess`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qprocess.html#details) class. Use one QProcess by task and connect your scheduler to QProcess signals (like started, error, etc.). You can to get the native pid of the process and stop it by sending the kill or terminate signal.

Regarding the scheduler, a set of timer should do the trick.

Hope that helps